# Unix xxd -r -p command NodeJS equivalent

Tags: node.js, shell, unix, sh

I am currently trying to convert a encryption shell script to a Nodejs version of it, and I am a bit stuck on this one command:

"ENCRYT_KEY = $(printf '<Random_hex_string>' | xxd -r -p | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pkcs -pubin -inkey "public-key.pem" | base64)"

I could not replicate the functionality of "xxd -r -p" to NodeJS.

Has anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate it in nodeJS using the following codes:

```
const absolutePathToPublicKey = "<Path to public key>";
var absolutePath = path.resolve(absolutePathToPublicKey);
var publicKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8");
var encryptedAESKey = crypto.publicEncrypt({
  key: publicKey,
  padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING,
}, <your random key>);
```